# ASP.NET MVC3 short routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want modified routing and I need to have default routing (controller/action/id) but I want to add route to short url which take action from home controller. I need something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "ActionOnly",
                 "{action}",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Let´s say I have action Club in Home. So I want to work adress.com/Club but still I need adress.com/Articles (where articles is controller).

I am not sure how to do that. Is it posible? Or I must for everything made route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Club",
            "Club",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Club"}
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have list of action that you allowed in first route ?

routes.MapRoute(
                 "ActionOnly",
                 "{action}",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

If you want to allow

routes.MapRoute(
                 "ActionOnly",
                 "{action}",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 new { action = "Club|AnotherActions"} 
);
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can totally create a specialized route that will handle the very special URL like you want.

The route engine will stop after the first match. If it doesn't find your `Club`, it will fallback to the default one and responds to the `Articles`.

See this [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) to get more information about how it works.